# will paginate remote links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I need that will paginate helper generate link_to_remote to other controller?
I need this because information is inside a popup and the pagination is there.

OK Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3? If yes, I would suggest Kaminari instead of will_paginate, which is built on and for Rails 3, and support remote links.

Here's a quick tutorial : http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

Comment: Thanks I am using rails 2.3.8. However I am thinking to change to Rails 3.